# How to switch between sibiling in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onclick, state, rerender

Consider I have an App component like this :

```
import React from "react";
import Component from "./component";

function App() {
    const array = [
        { key : 1 } , { key : 2 } , { key : 3 } , { key : 4 }
    ]
  return (
    <div>
        {array.map( (item) => {
            <Component key={item.key} />
        })}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

And the component is:

```
import React , { useState } from "react";

function Component() {
    const [ style , setStyle ]= useState({
        height:"50px",width:"50px",backgroundColor:"blue"
    });
  return (
    <div style={style} onclick={} >
        Content
    </div>
  );
}

export default Component;
```

This will create a App div and inside it there will be four child div elements.

What I want is that ; whenever I click on one of the inner div , the remaining three div have to change it's color to red. Not once but every time when I click on any of the four.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a state to store the clicked (or say, the currently selected) `div`

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Component from "./component";

function App() {
    const [selectedDiv, setSelectedDiv] = useState(-1);

    const array = [
        { key : 1 } , { key : 2 } , { key : 3 } , { key : 4 }
    ]
  return (
    <div>
        {array.map( (item) => {
            <Component key={item.key} clickHandler={() => {setSelectedDiv(item.key)}} isColoured={(selectedDiv === item.key || selectedDiv < 0) ? false : true} />
        })}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Now in the `Component`, check for the `isColoured` prop, if it's `true`, apply the colour, else don't.

```
import React from "react";

function Component(props) {
  return (
    <div onClick={props.clickHandler} style={props.isColoured ? {height:"50px",width:"50px",backgroundColor:"red"} : null}>
        Content
    </div>
  );
}

export default Component;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add state

```
  const [selectedId, setSelectedId] = useState(null);
```

And then make a function to render in this case a Guide

```
const renderGuide = ({ item, index }) => {
    console.log(item)
    const backgroundColor = item.id === selectedId ? "#FFFFFF" : "#FFFFFF";
    return (
      <Guide
        item={item}
        index={index}
        onPress={() => setSelectedId(item.id)}
        style={{ backgroundColor }}
      />
    );
  };
```

Making this you can access to item selected by id

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach,

Track the selected div in the state (using the id) and change the `Component` color based on the selected div in the state.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [selectedId, setSelectedId] = useState(null);
  const array = [{ key: 1 }, { key: 2 }, { key: 3 }, { key: 4 }];
  return (
    <div>
      {array.map((item) => {
        return (
          <Component
            key={item.key}
            id={item.key}
            selectedPanel={selectedId === item.key || selectedId === null}
            onClick={() => setSelectedId(item.key)}
          />
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
}

function Component({ id, onClick, selectedPanel }) {
  return (
    <div
      className="panel"
      style={{ backgroundColor: selectedPanel ? "blue" : "red" }}
      onClick={onClick}
    >
      Content - {id}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Working code - https://codesandbox.io/s/zealous-clarke-r3fmf?file=/src/App.js:0-770

Hope this is the use case you are looking for. Let me know if you are facing any issues.